# tensorflow ffmpeg contrib output

Tags: python, ffmpeg, tensorflow

First, I want to say that I'm completely new to TensorFlow and machine learning in general.
I'm looking at the [ffmpeg](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/ffmpeg) contrib section and I see the example of decoding an audio file and I was wondering what is the vector output of decoding an audio file?  The code I'm running looks like:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.contrib import ffmpeg
with tf.Session() as sess:
    audio_binary = tf.read_file('test.wav')
    waveform = ffmpeg.decode_audio(audio_binary, file_format='wav',
                                   samples_per_second=16000, channel_count=1)
    audio = waveform.eval()
```

The `audio` variable then becomes a `numpy.ndarray` type that is a list of single element lists (about 620,000 elements total) that are all floats between (in my case) -0.50218207 and 0.39030123.  My question is: What do these numbers mean? Is this some sort of standard audio representation that I'm completely missing?

Comment: Is this more of a ffmpeg question than a tensorflow/machine learning question? Have you read ffmpeg documentation? 
https://ffmpeg.org/documentation.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each of those float values in the waveform represent the *amplitude* of the corresponding audio at a discrete moment in time depending on the sample rate (in this case, every 1/16,000th of a second). If you were looking at 2 channels of audio rather than 1, you'd have another similar ndarray, thereby giving you a 2d matrix of equally-spaced time-series data.

You can determine the frequency / pitch of the components of that waveform by looking for periodic cycles or changes in the amplitude. Crossovers from positive to negative and back again might represent the fundamental frequency, whereas smaller intra-period oscillations could represent harmonics and overtones of the sound. Usually this kind of analysis is performed using a Fast Fourier Transform or similar methodology. A TensorFlow implementation would certainly make for a fascinating read.